# Ubuntu 18.10 Not Booting Correctly After Upgrade

Tags: boot, 18.10

I just upgraded from 18.04 to 18.10 and am having some issues. When I start Ubuntu I get stuck on "A start job is running..." with no limit and that never ends. However, I can switch to tty2 and login from there. I then do `sudo mount -o rw,remount /` (because the filesystem is mounted as read-only for some reason) and `startx` to get to my desktop. Once I do that, everything works fine, but when I restart I have to do it all over again.

Comment: Where do you see "A start job is running..."? Is it after the Ubuntu login screen?

Comment: @unutbu It never gets to the login screen. I have nomodeset so, instead of the splash screen I see a bunch of text as it starts up and "A start job is running" is the last line before it hangs forever

Comment: If you google "A start job is running" you'll find there are a number of possible causes. You might try reading through those and seeing if any seem to match your situation. If you think of extra information that might provide clues, edit it into your question. That may attract new eyes to look at the problem. As a practical matter though, it might be easiest to backup your data and do a fresh install of 18.10.